# Vim highlighting weird parts of FORTRAN

Tags: vim, fortran90

I am using VIM theme molokai, if that makes any difference.

I have been learning FORTRAN lately and when I write a FORTRAN program using VIM, I have weird coloring depending on my whitespace.

For instance, if I tab things over as is (no indenting) I have this purple highlight on only a portion of the word (sometimes it isn't there, notice the PRINTs and READs).

[image: without tabs]

If I tab it over it looks normal:

[image: with tabs]

I am new to VIM (not to mention FORTRAN) so I am not sure what's happening, I don't mind tabbing over all the time but I think it looks a little ridiculous if the whole program is wasting that column of white space.

Comment: What is the name of the file you are editing ?

Comment: The name of the file is: temp.f90

Comment: Hmmm, your screen shots suggest that Vim might think the code is written in fixed form source in which statements begin in column 7.  The other widely-used programmer's editor typically assumes that a source file with `.f` extension is fixed form and I suspected that Vim might too.  Perhaps it does, but how to tell it otherwise I do not know.

Comment: Update: if I save & quit, upon reopening the file the purple highlight is gone and things are colored correctly.

Comment: I think you're right, it doesn't detect I am using modern and believes it is using fixed-form/punchcard until I reopen the file. I'll investigate further, and hopefully post an answer soon.

Comment: The reason it works when you quit and reopen is that the default behavior when you first create the file is to assume it is fixed format, and you get the crazy characters.  When you reopen the file, it correctly interprets the file as free format.  The fix is in @dwwork solution below.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you search `:help fortran`, you'll get a list of options that you can set.
These are the fortran options I set in my own .vimrc file. (I don't work with fixed-format code though) I know there are one or two fortran specific scripts that are available online, but I don't use them.

```
let fortran_free_source=1
let fortran_have_tabs=1
let fortran_more_precise=1
let fortran_do_enddo=1
```

Comment: Helpful, I need to make better use of the "help:" command. I solved my problem for now, I don't have to work with fixed much but it does come up here at work occasionally. My toggle keys are really helpful for this. Thank you for answering though, much appreciated :) I'll keep that in mind if other people as me.

Comment: I'm going to try this instead of the syntax file I found tomorrow in order to compare. There are somethings the file added that I find a little conflicting (with my current vimrc settings).

Comment: Just make sure you read through the help docs! `fortran_free_source` assumes all free-form, `fortran_have_tabs` prevents it from highlighting tabs, but I set the `expandtab` option later on, which turns all tabs into spaces. The docs also describe a way to set certain file extensions to be free or fixed. Also see `help:ft-fortran-indent`.

Comment: Just marked yours as the answer, albeit that may not be as "full" of things as the fortran.vim file I specified in my answer. The results are much cleaner, simply because I just needed proper syntax highlighting and simpler indenting (to work with my current indenting settings). Besides, all of my fortran is in modern; I don't open many fixed-format files.

Answer (score 3):

Vim was using fixed-format/punchcard when I created a new .f90 file. In order to differentiate it, [I found this.](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Source+code+editors) 
I copied it to my ~/.vim/syntax/ directory and added the following lines to my .vimrc (also specified at following link)

```
nmap <S-F> :set syntax=fortran<CR>:let b:fortran_fixed_source=!b:fortran_fixed_source<CR>:set syntax=text<CR>:set syntax=fortran<CR>
nmap <C-F> :filetype detect<CR>
```

Allowing me to bind Shift-F to switch formats, and Ctrl-F to auto detect.

Answer (score 1):

You can install the [Fortran F90/95 indentation rules script](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2299) in `~/.vim/after/indent`, and it should fix the index errors.